# RTS Pathfinding without collision between units Options

Tags: unity, ai, path-finding, collision-avoidance

Ever since I made my units move to a certain location a problem has popped up that of course if I try to make two or more units go to the same place they fight for the same spot. Am I just being stupid and unity already has a way around this or do I need to do something specific? I have looked into flow field path finding but no way on how to implement it. I dont want to have to use a ready made script but some pointers and other options are more than welcome.

Comment: Don’t make them go to the same spot... use offsets and put each unit to the goal location with its offset.

Comment: What do you mean by "no way on how to implement it"? What have you tried so far based on your research online and [in our archive of existing Q&A](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/160412/39518), and where are you stuck?

Comment: This has been asked a million times before. Search for boids, swarm pathfinding, etc

Comment: I dont know if I should do so via a script or making my component etc, Greg.